# Change format input type='date' from mm-dd-yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I am trying to change date format in laravel from `mm-dd-yyy` to `dd-mm-yyyy`

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="joining_date" id="joining_date" required>
```

I tried even to put `timezone="[[timezone]]"` but nothing changes.

Comment: $model->joining_date->format('Y-m-d')

Answer (score 3):

Convert that date in controller before feeding to database like this :

```
$originalDate = $request->joining_date;
$newDate = date("dd-mm-YYYY", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Or if you want to show in view the same date

```
{{ date("dd-mm-YYYY", strtotime($date_from_controller)); }}
```

if you want to pre populate input field then

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="joining_date" id="joining_date" value="{{ date("dd-mm-YYYY", strtotime($date_from_controller)); }}" required>
```

if you want to change the format of input date then

```
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" required pattern="(?:30))|(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-31))/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])|(?:(?!02)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}-(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])">
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('mm-dd-yyy', $input)
  ->format('dd-mm-yyyy'); `
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Furthermore this does not solve op's problem since he wants to change the format of the input, not the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$date =  date('d-m-Y', strtotime($request->date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_create_from_format('mm-dd-yyy', $input)->format('dd-mm-yyyy');
```

Comment: while this code may answer the question, adding some explanations on why and how would improve the quality of the answer